# Java relative path start from my src folder

Tags: java

I wanna use relative path start from my src folder to get file from resource folder.

```
File myFile = new File("/src/main/resources/filefolder/file.xml");
```

When I try this:

```
File myFile = new File("../src/main/resources/filefolder/file.xml");
```

Or this:

```
File myFile = new File("../../../../src/main/resources/filefolder/file.xml");
```

I get:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /srv/../src/main/resources/filefolder/file.xml(No such file or directory)
```

My file structure:

```
-src
   -main
       -java
           -com.my.site
              -task
                 -MyClass.java
       -resources
```

Comment: you'll have to give complete path for this what you see in windows explorer.

Comment: It depends on where the above code is written in the file structure. We need more info to help. Could you post the file structure?

Comment: Where would be your `src` folder, after you have compiled your program, and packaged it into a JAR file?

Comment: Test it: `File myFile = new File("resources/filefolder/file.xml");` without leading '/'

Comment: Your `src` folder won't be there at execution time. Rethink.

Comment: @YonahKarp i edit my question with file structure

Comment: I don't know why you need to pass full absolute path to get a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see you are asking about the relative path but seems like you want to just read the file from resources, I believe the most common way to read resources is by using the class loader, example:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("filefolder/file.xml").getFile());
```

Comment: So in that case your resource path should be `filefolder/file.xml` right?

Comment: File file = null;
        ClassLoader loader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        URL url = loader.getResource("file.xml");
        if (url != null && url.getFile() != null) {
            file = new File(url.getFile());
        } 
this way it checking if file exists

Answer (score 5):

your path is correct, just add dot before src, to indicate that you are searching relative path to project root directory, in other case you'll search by absolute path

```
 File myFile = new File("./src/resources/filefolder/file.xml");
```

if doesn't work - try this:

```
File myFile = new File("src/resources/filefolder/file.xml");
```

anyway you can run this to check what is your root dir:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(new File("").getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Comment: While this might technically work, it ignores the fact that relying on the `src` folder is a bad idea, since it only exists during compile time, but not necessarily later, when running the program. So by answering the literal question instead of the actual question behind it, you can be sure that the next question will follow "Why doesn't this work" ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Just a little explanation... What you want to do is get a resource from the resource folder, that's a quite typical task.

What you do have to realize is, that the whole /src/main/etc. structure is there to structure your **source code**, in other words, the .java files (and resource files). In your compiled program, this structure will not longer exist in the same way, so relying on a `src` directory is a very, very bad idea.

This structure is there for maven:

`src/main` -> Everything that should be part of the "program" all the time
`src/test` -> Everything that should only be part of the "program" when running automated tests

`src/main/java` -> .java files that need to be there always
`src/main/resources` -> Resources (images, templates, etc.)  that need to be there always

`src/test/java` -> .java files that are only needed during automated tests (for example, the automated tests themselves)
`src/test/resources` -> Resources that are only used in automated tests, for example, files to compare results against, etc.

Where does this lead us? It leads to the simple fact, that, in the end, the whole src/main and src/test will simply not exist and indeed, java and resources will be added together (you can check this by looking at a .jar file - it can be opened with any Zip-Program). This is, why @LazerBanana is entirely correct: You do not try to navigate directories, you ask for resources and the resources are inside your classpath - and it does not matter, if they are in the resources or java folder (because that's just to keep your source code structured). In your class path, both folders come together.